# I want to use Resource !! (Xamarin.Forms 's custom renderer)

Tags: android, xamarin, resources, tableview

I'm trying to making a Table with Xamarin.Forms for Android.

First, there is no border on Table. So!

I made a border.xml file and make shape

but when I do build this, an ***error occurred***

[image]

***'Invalid start tag shape'***

I want to know how to fix it.

And ! , Sorry for more question,

after make resource .xml file I want to put in SetBackgroundResource(int resid)

using resid in Resource.Designer.cs.

How I make resid(resource id) for border.xml 's shape and use it?

Thank you Soooooooooooooo much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had a similar problem, I had created a `Converter`. You can find more example on Xamarin site https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/